# Different NAS speed on different Windows

Tags: windows, nas

I have a WD My Cloud NAS. File download speed from NAS via SMB is like 20 MB/s on Windows XP and 40 MB/s on Windows 7 on the same PC. Why?

### Windows 7

Copy speed: 45-53 MB/s

NAS cpu load (smbd, from top): 50-60%

### Windows XP

Copy speed: 22 MB/s

NAS cpu load (smbd, from top): 26-28%

Answer (score 1):

Because Windows XP uses SMB1, which isn’t all that great. Windows 7, on the other hand, uses SMB2, which is quite an improvement.

The CPU of your NAS is the limiting factor here. SMB2 is much more efficient, thus allowing for higher transfer rates.

Microsoft has a [Technet blog article on that](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2008/11/11/file-server-performance-improvements-with-the-smb2-protocol-in-windows-server-2008/), containing this picture:

[image]

The first spike is an SMB2 transfer, while the much slower transfer is done using SMB1.

Of course, Wikipedia also has an [article on SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block).

Comment: I doubt that since CPU load on the NAS with Windows XP is under 30%

Comment: Looking at the load average doesn’t really tell you what’s limiting. I may have worded it badly/wrong, but with SMB1 the CPU is of course mostly idle because the whole transfer involves a lot of (slow) roundtrips over the network. With SMB2, you should see much higher CPU load. Of course, it may still use only one core.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if the CPU was the bottleneck I would see constant 100% CPU load. See also what I've wrote about iperf.

Comment: Not necessarily. It's mostly I/O, after all. iperf isn't Samba and cannot be used to measure or predict Samba performance. Like I wrote: It's SMB1 vs SMB2. // edit: Or are you perhaps saying that iperf is also slower on XP?

Comment: Haven't measured it with iperf under Win7, but it's slower as SMB file transfer under Win7. And I'm sorry, but I don't think that CPU requirements matter if you have CPU usage at ca. 30%.

Comment: Well if you think my answer doesn’t solve the mystery, please update your question with more information, perform more tests (using iperf 3, large files, both XP and 7) and provide the actual test results, not some interpretation.

Comment: Edited question

Comment: Those values are exactly as expected. With SMB1, most time is lost in communication overhead. With SMB2 either Samba runs into some CPU limit or the network interface in your NAS is at capacity.